# External properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a java,spring and not spring boot command line program with maven , which when i build a jar with all dependencies using maven-assembly-plugin , it includes application.properties, what i need to know is how to read the external application.properties and not the jar one.

I am reading the property file as:

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
```

If I print the classpath, the classpath does only include the jar and not the current directory.

Comment: It is never a good idea to try to access an external file outside the project because you won't have that file available in production. If you need a file, add it to your resources folder in `src/main/` and you will have it available

Comment: @JAsgarov , i want on production environment external property file and in development in the jar. this way it makes easy to hide the production property variables like DB password etc. is it not a good approach? what are the alternatives...

Comment: Have you tried setting the SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION env variable and setting its value to the full path of your external properties file?

Comment: Or pass spring.config.location as a command line program argument when starting the app?

Comment: @JonH i tried already. Didnot worked , this is not a spring boot application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:/etc/config/my-custom-config.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
```

This `ignoreResourceNotFound` is available since spring 4.3 and is pretty self-explanatory.

You can also opt for "programmatic" approach. In pure spring  (not spring boot as you've mentioned in the question):

```
@Configuration
public class CommonConfig {
...
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            ppc.setLocations(new FileSystemResource("/etc/config/my-custom-config.properties"),
                    new ClassPathResource("config/application.properties"),
            return ppc;
        }
...
}
```

`FileSystemResource` is for accessing resources available externally in the file system

`ClassPathResource`  is for accessing resources in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

We use dynamically generated configuration files that are injected with environment specific secrets. The combination to get everything aligned is as follows:

Code:

```
    myFunction(@Value("${custom.configuration.name}") final String customConfigurationName) {
        InputStream inputStream=new ClassPathResource(customconfigFileName).getInputStream()){}
        ...
    }
```

Template - Add a hard required path as this confirms the file is on disk and loaded:

```
- name: SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION
  value: file:./config/schema-${ENV}.yml
  ...
- name: custom.configuration.name
  value: file:config/schema-${ENV}.yml
```